# syndip dataset for benchmark variant

Tags: vcf, public-dataset, variants

I have a question about syndip dataset : https://github.com/lh3/CHM-eval .
I'm struggling to find the syndip vcf.

In the release ( https://github.com/lh3/CHM-eval/releases ), we have a file named : `rep2.37.broad.hc.raw.vcf.gz`, that i don't know what it is. And we have a file named `CHM-evalkit-20180222.tar` which contains `full.37m.vcf` and other files (bed, eval ...).
So i did my search and according to this file: they mentioned that full.37m.vcf is the truth dataset. ( https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/suppl/2018/10/29/456103.DC1/456103-1.pdf Page 16).

The problem is that the file `rep2.37.broad.hc.raw.vcf.gz` contain variants with `MQ, DP, GQ` ... that I need to extract. But the `full.37m.vcf` doesn't contain this information.. ( just `Chrom pos ref alt and QUAL`.)

So I tried to intersect `rep2.37.broad.hc.raw.vcf.gz` with `full.37m.vcf` and take the variant that present in two files, with the DP MQ GQ in `rep2.37.broad.hc.raw.vcf.gz`.

Is that okay? Since I don't know what is `rep2.37.broad.hc.raw.vcf.gz`.

And I also noticed that the QUAL in the `full.37m.vcf` is always 30. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the truth VCF, it is `full.37m.vcf`. `rep2.37.broad.hc.raw.vcf.gz` is an example call set by GATK.

Comment: thank you for the response  !